# regex python string ignore special character

Tags: python, regex

This is what i have now :

```
import re

x = "From: Joyce IP: 192.111.1.1 Source: 192.168.1.1"    
x = x.replace(' ', '')
m = re.findall('(?<=:)\S+', x)
print m
```

And I want to have a output like this to make this **$ script.py > result.txt**:

```
Joyce 192.111.1.1 192.168.1.1
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Instead of finding the matches of the text you want as the result, it may be easier to replace the stuff you don't want:

```
>>> import re
>>> x = "From: Joyce IP: 192.111.1.1 Source: 192.168.1.1"
>>> re.sub(r'\w+:\s', '', x)
'Joyce 192.111.1.1 192.168.1.1'
```

However, if you prefer to use `re.findall()` here is one option that is similar to your current approach:

```
>>> ' '.join(re.findall(r'(?<=:\s)\S+', x))
'Joyce 192.111.1.1 192.168.1.1'
```

You need the `\s` in the negative lookbehind because there is a space after each of the colons in your input string.

Comment: that is exactly what i'm talking about this is easy to someone else  damn, sorry to ask F.J why did you use sub instead of search of findall ?

Comment: @PythonNewbie I added a version that uses findall, but I generally find it easier to understand expressions that don't use lookbehind or lookahead, and using sub makes that possible.

Answer (score 0):

a slight change to your code (don't remove the spaces, and include them in the look behind) works perfectly:

```
import re

x = "From: Joyce IP: 192.111.1.1 Source: 192.168.1.1"    
m = re.findall('(?<=:\s)\S+', x)
print " ".join(m)
```

Answer (score 0):

```
import re

x = "From: Joyce IP: 192.111.1.1 Source: 192.168.1.1"    

reg = r"\d{1,3}(?:[.]\d+){3}"

m = re.findall(reg, x)

for i in m:
  print(i)
```

Result :
192.111.1.1
192.168.1.1

Comment: A cleaner way of addressing the problem, for those who are looking for answers.